# Clash Royale Quest Chests

Tags: clash-royale

*Background info - the October 9 Update introduced Quests into Clash Royale, in which you complete Quests to earn Quest Points, and once you earn a certain amount of Quest Points, you earn a chest with zero unlock time.*

How many Points are required for each Chest, and is the order of Chests available already predetermined (like chests dropping from battle), or is it random with a percent chance for each chest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the following chests, with the number of Quest Points required in brackets

- Gold Chest (50)
- Giant Chest (300)
- Magical Chest (300)
- Epic Chest (350)
- Legendary Chest (400)
- Super Magical (500)

How they are awarded (or proposed for awarding) I do not know.