# Quests in Clash Royale

Tags: clash-royale

Quests are one of the newer features added to Clash Royale. Completing quests (given to you daily) contribute points to unlocking a chest (once you click "Collect Reward") assigned to you in the quest log page. More rare chests require more points to unlock and vice versa.

My question comes in two parts:
1) Is there a limit to how many completed quests I can hold before collecting my rewards?
2) Does the game know I've completed the mission and count it towards my total before I collect the reward?
Example: I have 490/500 reward points for unlocking a chest. I complete a quest worth 20 points. In game, until I collect the reward my chest shows 490/500. Does the game really know that I am 510/500 (or 10 points/X new required points)?

If you are wondering "why ask?" It is becoming increasingly imperative for free-to-play players to maximize their chance at getting new cards. If you earn a super magical chest in arena 5, it does you no good open the chest once grinding to arena 11 because the chest still has an "arena 5 value" assigned to it. If a card is going to be released Tuesday, and I complete and collect all points required to open it Monday... Waiting until Tuesday to open the chest is pointless because it will only have Monday's-specific card pool to pull from.

Comment: From my experience, it seems the max amount of quests you can hold at anyone time is 3. So if you had all three completed, I imagine you would not get any new ones until you cash them in. As for what the game knows, there's really no way of knowing that unless it has been released by the devs. The game knows when a quest is complete (because it shows you its completed) but whether or not it counts it towards your total is another question. I would assume it isnt counted until collected, but again we would need the dev's input to be sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clash Royale Quest Chests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319471/clash-royale-quest-chests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can hold up to 3 quests, (plus 1 more, if there's a special event quest, identified by blue background). It doesn't matter if those are completed or not, they only get cleared once you claim them. It's best to have at least one slot free when the reset time comes around. (By the way, a completed event quest don't expire immidiately.)
2. Through my testing it sure seems obvious that the reward point chest only cares about *claimed* quests. That is, if you had enough points to claim a chest, cashed in the quests to claim the chest, then went up or down an arena and only after that claim the point chest, *your next chest will be of the latest arena.*

Also, you can't claim quests if your current point chest is maxed out, so I believe (if you think you can get higher arena in a reasonable time) the optimal play is to hold to claiming your point chest untill you've either:

- Run out of quest slots to hold completed quests (I do think completing quests is more optimal than hoping for a better quest chest)
- Got to a higher arena
- At a risk of going down an arena at your next battle (Remember, you loose about 30 crowns per loss and have about 50 crown leeway before actually going down an arena)

Comment: I'm going to try out the chest level timing the next time it's about to change. I'd bet that if it's ready to be claimed (point counter is full) and I go down an arena, that I'm getting the lower arena level chest.

Comment: I managed to do some testing and I'm now more confident of my answer.